# ipyparallel with mpi cannot find engines

Tags: python, mpi4py, ipython-parallel

I'm trying to get a basic ipyparallel environment working using mpi4py as described [in the ipyparallel documentation](http://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mpi.html). After starting the ipcluster, I load ipython and try to create a client but it has no IDs and accessing the directview returns a `NoEnginesRegistered` exception.

Steps I take to get to this point:

1. Create a new environment: `conda create --name=ipyparallel` and `source activate ipyparallel`
2. Install ipyparallel and mpi4py: `conda install ipyparallel mpi4py`
3. Create a new ipython profile: `ipython profile create --parallel --profile=mpi`
4. Edit ~/.ipython/profile_mpi/ipcluster_config.py and add `c.IPClusterEngines.engine_launcher_class = 'MPIEngineSetLauncher'`
5. Launch cluster with `ipcluster start --profile=mpi`

Then I launch ipython and run the following:

```
import ipyparallel as ipp
c = ipp.client(profile="mpi")
c[:] # <-- NoEnginesRegistered exception
```

Step 5 reports that "Engines appear to have started successfully" and I can see that a process named "mpiexec" is running. Strangely, I tried these same steps on another machine with the same OS and there it worked with no problems. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem for anyone coming here with a similar problem. During installation I had added the notebook extension to jupyter's global config. Not sure why that caused this problem but it's fixed now. Outside of a conda environment, I ran:

```
sudo pip install ipyparallel
sudo jupyter nbextension disable --py ipyparallel
sudo jupyter nbextension uninstall --py ipyparallel
sudo pip uninstall ipyparallel
```

and then inside the conda environment I can connect to the ipyparallel engines.